# H.265 to H.264 batch file command

Tags: cmd.exe, matroska

What can be added to this batch file command line that will enable it to change H.265 to H.264?

```
if not exist newfiles md newfiles
for %%a in ("*.mkv") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vcodec copy -acodec 
copy "newfiles\%%~na.mp4" 
pause
```

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

This site has examples for encoding videos as H264. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264

Maybe something like this: `ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -b:v 3M -c:a aac -b:a 160k "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"`